# Assigning a variable to part of a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I am writing a program in python3 and Im stuck on one part. My problem is I have a variable. example:

```
    variable = 12345
```

so I want to assign a specific variable to one part of the value of the other variable.

Ive tried example:

```
    variable[2] = 55
```

(this is an example but hopefully im coming off clear enough)
so I want to take the 3rd digit in "12345" 12[3]45
so the "3" I want to assign a variable basically from a place inside another variable.
What sucks is it has to be inside that variable. Ive thought about passing it as a string instead but I think that will change the whole rest of the script being that now its a string. 
so I thought also about each time I need to call that variable I can pass it as a string to another variable but im trying not to get swamped with a million str and int swaps. I hope Ive made this understandable...I get that its not very clear lol but Ive confused my self with this script any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In any case we have to perform conversions to strings and lists. 
We can achieve this in compatible way with python2.x and python3.x as follow:

```
# input variable
variable = 12345
# convert that variable to list
variable_lst = [int(i) for i in str(variable)]
# change necessary digit by list index
variable_lst[2] = 55
# reverse conversion then assign updated data to variable
variable = int(''.join(str(j) for j in variable_lst))  # 125545
```

Answer (score 0):

you should convert  your variable to list type, so you could change any index of it:

```
var = 12345
var_list= list(str(var))
var_list[2]=55
var_list= int(''.join(str(i) for i in var_list))
```